# jqgrid 4.13.1 search filter error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I use jqgrid 4.13.1. In the jqfiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/9ezy09ep/162/, when I try to filter the list like this (important : replace %tab% with the tab char, ascii value=9):

Customer ID > Contains > %tab%HANAR

I get the error in the file jquery-1.12.0.min.js :

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: bad control character in string literal at line 1 column 67 of the JSON data
```

How to escape the tab char in the value field of the jqgrid filter ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I analysed the problem. The problem exist because of usage `xmlJsonClass.toJson` in [the line](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.13.1/js/grid.formedit.js#L315) of code of free jqGrid 4.13.1. The line come from old jqGrid (see [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.7.0/js/grid.formedit.js#L245)). I thought already to remove the usage of `xmlJsonClass.toJson` and to use only `JSON.stringify`, but I hold the usage of old methods hoping to hold better compatibility with old versions of jqGrid.

The problem is that JSON standard (see [here](http://json.org/)) **require** to escape only `"` and `\` symbols and some other symbols, like tab,  **could be** escaped:

[image]

The method `xmlJsonClass.toJson` generates the string, which escapes tab (converts to two characters `\t`) and `JSON.stringify` don't do this.

The problem come later after one *deserializes* `postData.filters` using `$.parseJSON`, which calls `JSON.parse` internally.

I made modification of the code of the Searching Dialog to use `JSON.stringify` as the first choice (which exists in all modern web browsers and can be included in old web browsers by including [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js)). I will continue to use `xmlJsonClass.toJson` for the fallback scenario only.

I committed [the fix](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commit/47c4d61a353298aa76859281e17d15e38a2f5ef4) to GitHub, which fixes the problem. See http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/9ezy09ep/163/, which uses the latest sources from GitHub.